# what is the codec for mp4 videos in python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, mp4, codec

```
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
```

The above line is used for avi video.  In the same fashion, which codec do we use for mp4 videos in Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you consider any of this answers the correct one? Can you mark it ?

Answer (score 47):

You can also use `mp4v`

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
```

where the videowriter should look like this:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4',fourcc, 15, size)
```

But there are more codecs available for mp4. You can see the list of them by setting `fourcc = -1`, it will show a list like this:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: format mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)
fourcc tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' codec_id 000C
fourcc tag 0x31637661/'avc1' codec_id 001B
fourcc tag 0x33637661/'avc3' codec_id 001B
fourcc tag 0x31766568/'hev1' codec_id 00AD
fourcc tag 0x31637668/'hvc1' codec_id 00AD
fourcc tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' codec_id 0002
fourcc tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' codec_id 0001
fourcc tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' codec_id 0007
fourcc tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' codec_id 003D
....
```

All of them supports mp4 but `h264` is supported by Web browsers if you want to serve the video into the web.

Comment: How do you generate that list? Where do you set fourcc = -1?

Comment: literally pass `fourcc = -1` to the constructor of `VideoWriter` and then this output will appear

Answer (score 21):

The codec is H.264.

One of these should work for you:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'h264')
#or 
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'x264')
#or
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
```

However, I should warn you that you'll probably need to have `ffmpeg` and the `x264` libraries installed so since you are in Ubuntu, try doing this command in the **terminal**:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg x264 libx264-dev
```

Also, check out [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506132355/http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#saving-a-video) from OpenCV tutorials for more details as to the kinds of FourCC codes available for your platform.

In the above link, it says `X264` is the FourCC code you should use, but switch between them until you get it to work.

Comment: Out of all solutions installing the codec seperate from open cv 4 with `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg x264 libx264-dev` did the job to get it working on my Raspberry Pi 3. Thanks!

Comment: ffmpeg **rejects `"h264"`** for mp4 format containers. it says `FFMPEG: tag 0x34363268/'h264' is not supported with codec id 27 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'` but it **accepts `"avc1"`**, as listed in the other answer. both designate the same video compression, H.264/AVC, but the MP4 format only accepts specific tags. it's a standard.

Comment: Would H.264 work for the browser?

Comment: @MehdiCharife yes

Answer (score 6):

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v')
```

Always seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question. But, if anyone is facing an issue lately using the codec who can't get a saved video. They can use `0X00000021` as the codec value for OpenCV 3 and later.

Answer (score 1):

I had to reinstall ffmpeg and compile opencv from source in order to get this working. I documented the steps in this [blog post](https://www.swiftlane.com/blog/generating-mp4s-using-opencv-python-with-the-avc1-codec/).

Answer (score 0):

i just used fourcc as -1 and problem solved. my editor is vscode and os is windows.