# Python OpenCV Video Recording - Fourcc Codec Error

Tags: python, opencv, video-recording, fourcc

i'm trying to write a script to record camera display.

When i tried to run, i got the error:

`OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x5634504d/'MP4V' is not supported with codec id 12 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'`

`OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v'`

Here's my code:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

width = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MP4V")
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("captures/record.mp4", fourcc, 20, (width, height))

while True:
    is_camera_working, display = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("Camera Data", display)

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

cam.release()
writer.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

I tried to write `(*"mp4v")` , `("m","p","4","v")` in the `VideoWriter_fourcc`. Also i delete `fourcc` variable and just write `0x7634706d` as second argumnet of `VideoWriter` function.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103077/what-is-the-codec-for-mp4-videos-in-python-opencv) and [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/python-what-is-the-four-characters-fourcc-code-for-mp4-encoding-on-tx2/57701) threads. Still not works for me.

What is the problem and how can i solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are warnings -- I get the same warnings, but the code works, i.e. the image shows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just realise that i didn't write `writer.write(display)` in the while loop. It works now. Thanks everyone for their time!

Answer (score 1):

The codec identifier you need to use is "mp4v" (lowercase) instead of "MP4V":

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
```

Comment: I already tried that, i wrote it down after the code block.

Comment: The warning you pasted shows that you used "MP4V" -- can you try using 'mp4v' instead, and paste the warning you receive? (Just to be sure...)

Comment: I forgot the add `writer.write(display)` line. That was the problem. And also, i write with lower case "mp4v" again to check the output. There was no error message and record.mp4 was created but still, because of the `writer.write(display)` it was blank. Thank you for your time!